# Visual Studio code analysis in Jenkins

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, jenkins, continuous-integration

In VS2013 you can run the compiler for native code with the `/analyze` flag that will generate .xml files holding the output of the analyze. This will be interpreted by the UI and shown to the developer.

Is there a solution on how to integrate this into a **Jenkins** build or are any tool which can read such .xml files like the `vc.nativecodeanalysis.all.xml` and display it as a web page?

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins is essentially a dashboard that outsources tasks to other tools to "do their thing".

With .NET builds your only option is a freestyle build with heavy use of Windows Batch command post build steps or MSBuild steps.  Jenkins only knows the path to MSBuild that you tell it in "Manage Jenkins > Configure System"

After that it will outsource msbuild Post Build steps to MSBuild with the parameters you pass it.

Jenkins can consume JUnit test results and many other tools are written to convert test results into JUnit for Jenkins to consume.  The mountain is brought to Jenkins rather than the other way around.

If MSBuild doesn't produce a graph, Jenkins unfortunately won't be able to.

You might keep an eye on the Static Analysis plugin over time to see if it adds support for this.